# how to skip current user when regex validation is used in laravel?

Tags: php, regex, laravel, validation

I want to use unique feature in the validation. The below code works fine when i pass the `\Auth::user()->id` in the end

```
'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users'.\Auth::user()->id,
```

How do i pass the user id when regex pattern is validated which takes the validation parameter in array format.

```
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(),[
    'phone' => [
                   'required',
                   'unique:personal_details, phone',
                   'regex:/((\(\d{3}\) ?)|(\d{3}-))?\d{3}-\d{4}/'
               ]
]);
```

Comment: Could you please be more clear about what you want to achieve in the second validation?

Comment: i want to skip the current authenticated user model from the table when regex validation is done.

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel version 5.2

Comment: I'm afraid that it could not be done with standard Laravel rules. The only thing that you can do is creating a custom validation rule that performs. Take a look at this section on the Laravel docs https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Comment: You have a typo in your `email` rule.  You're missing a comma after `users`.  I still can't understand what you're asking though, even reading the comments here.